# Stored procedure taking long time

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure. Following is the main body of the procedure:

> insert into table_insert(col1, col2, col3........col50)
>   select col1, col2, function_1(var1,var2), function_2(var20,var21).....function_50(var50,var51)
>   from table_select

In table_select has 45000 rows. This procedure is taking more than 36 hours to transfer all rows to table_insert.in function_1 to function_50 using 4 different table data when required.
I put index properly to all table properly.

Here a single row taking average 2.5 to 3.1 second to be processed and transferred from   table_select to table_insert
Could you please tell me why this procedure is taking long time?

Comment: What is happening in `function_*`? Without knowing this, it would be impossible to understand what may be best approach. Also what sort of indexes exist on `table_insert`? On the surface moving 45K rows from one table to another should be very fast.  You are likely losing time in those functions and/or in updating indexes on insert.

Comment: its getting value from other table and return those value.

Comment: And you do that 50 times for every single one of your 45K records?  Does that not strike you as odd that you would make 2.25M queries to complete this procedure? You really need to take a step back and re-evaluate your approach to this problem. For example, can a table join be used?

Comment: @Mike: i use (add index syntax for adding index) and used those columns which are used for searching value

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your functions use indexes to lookup the data (other than to make the approach slightly less horrible). You can't expect to in essence perform 50 subqueries for every single record in your table and have it perform in any sort of reasonable manner.

Comment: @mike: You are absolutely right. Could you guide me please which approach i should follow?

Comment: Like I said, you need to take a step back and take a look at the tables from which you are deriving data.  Can you simply join that data in `table_select` with the data in the table(s) you are using for "lookup"?

Comment: yes, but the problem is that in total i am deriving 4 different table so if i join all those so it will become a huge set. is not it?

Comment: Share the code for your _function_ and the real code for the insert.

Comment: @Samiul If you could join 5 different tables in the select portion of your SQL and those joins were reasonable, indexed joins, chances are you would see several orders of magnitude improvement. As AgRizzo points out though, there is no guidance that can be given without understanding the underlying DB schema and what your objectives are in real-world terms.